# Make copy of Google Spreadsheet on google shared drives via apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive

This code make a copy of the given file, gives it a new name and moves it to destination.

```
DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).makeCopy(fileName,fileDestination)
```

How can I have the same function when I have all my files on Shared Drive? I have activated the Drive API and everything works fine except the code above!

Comment: I think that your script can be used for copying the Spreadsheet to another folder under the Shared Drive. So, can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal? If an error occurs, can you provide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this code instead:

```
function copytoMyDrive(){

  var destinationMyDriveId = "yourdestinationfolderid in my Drive";
  var sheet = "your sheet ID";
  Drive.Files.copy({title:'Copy of file',parents:[{id:destinationMyDriveId}]},sheet, {supportsAllDrives: true})
}
```

The title parameter is optional if you want the copied file to have a different name. After running the code you should have a copy of the file that was in your shared Drive on your specified folder in My Drive.

Reference:

- [Files:Copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/copy)